# Excel calculation in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm struggling a bit with an excel calculation that needs to be written in C#.

The calculation in excel looks like this:

```
=(-0,7333 * (1) ^ 2 + 3,3167 * 1 + 1,625) * 1.821 * 16/1000 * 1,125
```

In C# I have this:

```
Math.Pow(-0.7333 * (1.0), 2) + 3.3167 * 1.0 + 1.625) * 1821.3125 * 16.0 / 1000 * 1.125
```

The excel calculation gives me the result of `138`

The C# calculation gives me the result of `179.63554194392623`

Of course, the C# calculation should match the result of the Excel calculation and while I'm certainly not a genious when it comes to math, I fail to spot the difference in this calculation :-/

Can anyone point this math-blind being here in the right direction? :-)

Any help/input is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

**Edit:**
Thanks for all your answers! :-) I just learned something new right there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change format of the cell in EXcel and it will show you the `exact` result.

Also `-0,7333 * (1) ^ 2` in Excel is `-0.7333 * Math.Pow((1.0), 2)` and not as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Your error was that excel will do the power before muliplication:

```
double q = (-0.7333 * Math.Pow((1.0), 2) + 3.3167 * 1.0 + 1.625) * 1821.3125 * 16.0 / 1000 * 1.125;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing parenthesis in the excel expression:

```
=((-0,7333 * 1) ^ 2 + 3,3167 * 1 + 1,625) * 1.821 * 16/1000 * 1,125
```

That returns:

```
179.60472015642
```

Otherwise the power will be applied only to "1".
Moreover, in the excel formula, the term 1821 is missing decimal digits. So:

```
=((-0,7333 * (1) )^ 2 + 3,3167 * 1 + 1,625) * 1821,3125 * 16/1000 * 1,125
```

That returns:

```
179,635541943926
```

Much better!!